Is there a specific name for matrices which when multiplied by themselves give Identity times a Coefficient?
Consider $AA=cI$
Where $A$ is a matrix, $c$ a number, and $I$ the Identity matrix.
Is there a name for matrices with this specific property?

Hello :) These are matrices with minimal polynomial $\mu(x) =x^2-c$.

Well, since you can multiply by $\frac 1{\sqrt c}$ unless $c=0$, these are basically the matrices with $A^2=\mathbb 1$.  In any case, I am aware of no universally recognized name for them.

Matrices satisfying $A^2 = I$ are sometimes called involutory. If $A^2 = cI$ for $c \neq 0$, then $\frac 1{\sqrt{c}}A$ is involutory. If $A^2 = 0$, then $A$ is nilpotent.

This was useful, thanks everybody.

We might take the Input given by @BenGrossmann to claim that $A$ is a Scaled Involuntary Matrix , when having Non-Zero Scaling factor $\sqrt{c}$. That will work out with Complex $c$ values too !

@Jochen, re, unless $A$ itself is already scalar!

Auto-Correct Issue in my earlier comment : I wanted to type Scaled "Involutory" Matrix there !
